# How can I change link on View Button in Laravel Nova for one resource only?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I want to change the link on Laravel Nova View Button for a specific resource. By default, it moves to the default Details page but I want to redirect it to the another page that I have already made.

For example, I have a resource named Tools. So, in the default table, when I click on view button of a tool with id=20(say), it goes to resources/tools/20 which is the default laravel nova details page, but I want to change this link to tools/api-test. How can I do this?

Please give some suggestions related to it. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Edit and post your code

Comment: I have not written the code. I am just asking that on clicking on View button, it redirects to resources/resource-name/resource-id but I want to redirect it to some other link. How can I do that?

Comment: without code sample no-one can't help you here.

Comment: Edited my question please check

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to override the default view link, but you can create a [`URL` field](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#url-field) and link to an arbitrary value.

```php
URL::make('Receipt', fn () => $this->receipt_url)
```

The second argument can be a function that returns the URL that you wish to go.